# How can I make the computer beep in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, beep

How do I make the computer's internal speaker beep in C# without external speakers?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

In .Net 2.0, you can use [`Console.Beep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep).

```
// Default beep
Console.Beep();
```

You can also specify the frequency and length of the beep in milliseconds.

```
// Beep at 5000 Hz for 1 second
Console.Beep(5000, 1000);
```

Comment: I just tested in Win 7 x64 RC, and although the internal speaker didn't beep, there was a beep through speakers when I had them plugged in and on.  I guess it's just the internal (mobo) speaker that won't beep.  Thanks for the info @Lck.

Comment: And here is why: http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: It should work on x64, but the sound will come out trough the normal speakers (which can be muted).
http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: i have x86 but no sound is played from the internal speaker ! Only external speaker ?!!!!

Comment: @LorenzCK That's... not 100% true?  I have Win7 64 and I am able to hear a full range of `Beep()`'s frequencies through external speakers.  However, +1 for the internal part, I never realized that.

Comment: @a_hardin Like I mentioned, "through external speakers," not built-in.  I haven't heard a built-in beep since XP, heh

Comment: The default is Beep(800,200).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep

Comment: If your app is sensitive to performance, this is better than using SystemSounds.Beep.Play(). Also consider using `Task.Run(() => Console.Beep(440, 500));`

Answer (score 161):

Use [`System.Media.SystemSounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.systemsounds) to get the sounds for various events, then [Play](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.systemsound.play) them:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Question.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
```

Comment: Unfortunately these system sounds require external speakers, which can't always be counted on.  It's definitely good to know these, though!

Comment: Now knowing that x64 versions of Windows requires speakers to hear the Console.Beep(), these options will work just as well.

Comment: My Vista x64 on laptop with inbuilt speakers doesn't play Console.Beep() but these are fine.

Answer (score 23):

The solution would be,

```
Console.Beep
```

Answer (score 16):

Print the [bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) (ASCII code 7). You can use the escape sequence `\a` from alert/alarm <sup>1</sup>.

```
Console.WriteLine("\a")
```

<sup>1</sup> `\b` is for backspace

Answer (score 10):

It is confirmed that **Windows 7 and newer versions** (at least 64bit or both) **do not use system speaker** and instead they route the call to the default sound device.

So, using `system.beep()` in win7/8/10 will not produce sound using internal system speaker. Instead, you'll get a beep sound from external speakers if they are available.

Comment: But there's no guarantee it works/beeps through sound card. On my Windows 10 machine there's no beep - sound card works of course

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this question while searching for the solution for myself.
You might consider calling the system beep function by running some kernel32 stuff.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool Beep(int freq, int duration);

        public static void TestBeeps()
        {
            Beep(1000, 1600); //low frequency, longer sound
            Beep(2000, 400); //high frequency, short sound
        }
```

This is the same as you would run powershell:

```
[console]::beep(1000, 1600)
[console]::beep(2000, 400)
```