# Can I generate different beeps using the computer speaker or is there only one

Tags: c#, beep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the computer beep in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321135/how-can-i-make-the-computer-beep-in-c)

Can the computer beep at different pitches or is there only one?

Comment: Did you even attempt to look for the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.beep.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Console.Beep method has two overloads: the first version is the default beep, and the second version receives two arguments—the frequency and the duration in milliseconds. Try following program to sample different beeps your c# code can make.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

    for (int i = 37; i <= 32767; i += 200)
    {
        Console.Beep(i, 100);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for example,

```
Console.Beep(5000, 1000);
```

Will beep @ 5000 MHz for 1 second

You can play with the HZ to control the tone

More on beep [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Beep(
    int frequency,
    int duration)
```

You can change the [frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1.aspx)

The frequency of the beep, ranging from `37 to 32767` hertz.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `kernel32.Beep` API, you can set the frequency manually: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.Beep

`dwFreq`: Specifies the frequency, in hertz, of the sound. This parameter must be in the range 37 through 32767 (0x25 through 0x7FFF).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the frequency.

See a good example. You can even play musics. [Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1.aspx)