# Is it possible to change the frequency of Console.Beep while playing?

Tags: c#, frequency, beep

I'd like to know if there is a way that I can let a program execute `int f = 37; Console.Beep( f, 10000 )` and while it plays, change the `f` variable so the sound actually changes.

EDIT: I don't want to use a loop which increases `f` because that'd make the sound stop playing for a little time (each iteration). And I know there are other ways, but I'd like to know about the Beep method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I generate different beeps using the computer speaker or is there only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414707/can-i-generate-different-beeps-using-the-computer-speaker-or-is-there-only-one)

Comment: Just use a `for` loop and execute updates to the `f` variable in-between calls to `Console.Beep` as this previous answer demonstrates.

Comment: @DerekBrown This will generate an increase that is not continuos. Every the time set, new frequency will play, which makes it change abruptly.

Comment: if you are really trying to play sounds, why not look at an actual library for playing sounds?

Comment: Console.Beep isn't suitable for playing *nice* music of any kind. Find a different tool for this job.

Comment: I understand that Beep isn't suitable for playing nice music. But I am asking a very precise question.

Comment: You asked how to make “the sound actually changes” and @Derek showed you how to do that. If that is not what you want, edit your question to tell us what you want because right now it is not anywhere near “precise”.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that many (most?) newer machines don't have a PC speaker anymore, so Console.Beep will keep silent on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play sounds in your console application and have a much wider control over what's being played, I suggest you to use the `SoundPlayer` class (MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx), give it a look to have an overview of its features).

The cons is that you have to create a `wav` file that produces the beep sound (it shouldn't be hard to find one googling a little bit) and a `wav` file for every different sound you want to implement in your application. You can put the files in your application directory, but you can also embed them as resources in your assembly:

```
private static SoundPlayer s_Beep;
private static SoundPlayer s_Buzz;

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    s_Beep = SoundPlayer(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.Beep.wav"));
    s_Beep.Load();

    s_Buzz = SoundPlayer(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.Buzz.wav")); 
    s_Buzz.Load();

    s_Beep.PlayLooping();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    s_Beep.Stop();

    s_Buzz.Play();

    // ...
}
```