# Play voice words sounds using Console.Beep .Net

Tags: c#, console, voice, beep

I use VS 2010, .Net 3.5, Win7 64 bits.

Can I use Console.Beep for "simule" human sounds (voice), maybe producing a synthesized voice sound ?

For example, using Beep for "simule" the sound of word "Error" ? any sample about it ?

Another samples using Console.Beep to play music chords and notes.

Is there any way I can get Console.Beep to play anything that sounds (voice, word Error) more like a chord or notes?

**I want only use Console.Beep.** (if it is possible,maybe)
Simulation, not real voice. I don't mind it sounds like R2D2.

Beep
[How can I make the computer beep in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321135/how-can-i-make-the-computer-beep-in-c)

Play musical chords , notes
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/6620fd81-974a-40d1-8599-66d6c7c7d22d/

http://oguzkoroglu.net/post/2011/01/16/ConsoleBeep().aspx

Comment: Human speech and music is a mix of a great number of frequencies whose intensity rapidly changes over time.  Console.Beep() is capable of neither, it will never sound better than R2D2.

Answer (score 8):

No IT IS NOT possible

you can find all you need in the `System.Speech.Synthesis Namespace`

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace SampleSynthesis
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
      SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

      // Configure the audio output. 
      synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

      // Speak a string.
      synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

*The SpeechSynthesizer class provides access to the functionality of a speech synthesis engine that is installed on the host computer. Installed speech synthesis engines are represented by a voice, for example Microsoft Anna.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx

Comment: which is the prerrequisites for use Speech.Synthesis ? any .net assembly ? any Win32 API or component installed in Windows?

Comment: I have edited my answer. you need to add System.Speech as reference as well

Comment: System.Speech works fine in Windows XP 32 bits, Windows 7 64 bits ? another system requeriment (any win32 api : kernel32,...) about System.Speech ?

Comment: from windows XP works fine (you don't need to install anything as it is part of the windows installation)

Comment: Only voice installed, Microsoft Anna (English United States). How can I installed more voice (Spanish) for System.Speech?

Comment: you have to install a third part voice. I'm using this one for my project

http://www.ivona.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

Hey there =) I was thinking of this too, so I searched the web but could not find anything.
worked on it a little myself and came up with this =).
its working pretty well!

I made 1 random number (int) generator in the " public partial class Form1 : Form " so it will load @ start.

Code :

> ```
>     private Random randomgen = new Random();
> ```

Below here i made integers for the 8 different sounds, and 8 for different speeds.

"beepgen1" until "8" in the code below is the frequency of the sound 
37-7000 Hertz  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link for more info on the "Console.Beep(FREQUENCY, MILISEC)"

> Example Place this code under a button and your pc will make a beep @
>   1000Hertz and 100Milisec long.
>
> "Console.Beep(1000, 100)"

```
            int beepgen1, beepgen2, beepgen3, beepgen4, beepgen5, beepgen6, beepgen7, beepgen8, beepgenn1, beepgenn2, beepgenn3, beepgenn4, beepgenn5, beepgenn6, beepgenn7, beepgenn8;

            beepgen1 = (randomgen.Next(37, 7000));
            beepgen2 = (randomgen.Next(37, 6000));
            beepgen3 = (randomgen.Next(37, 6000));
            beepgen4 = (randomgen.Next(37, 7000));
            beepgen5 = (randomgen.Next(37, 8000));
            beepgen6 = (randomgen.Next(37, 7000));
            beepgen7 = (randomgen.Next(37, 7000));
            beepgen8 = (randomgen.Next(37, 5000));
            beepgenn1 = (randomgen.Next(50, 200));
            beepgenn2 = (randomgen.Next(50, 250));
            beepgenn3 = (randomgen.Next(50, 300));
            beepgenn4 = (randomgen.Next(50, 200));
            beepgenn5 = (randomgen.Next(50, 250));
            beepgenn6 = (randomgen.Next(50, 200));
            beepgenn7 = (randomgen.Next(50, 300));
            beepgenn8 = (randomgen.Next(50, 250));

            Console.Beep(beepgen1, beepgenn1);
            Console.Beep(beepgen2, beepgenn2);
            Console.Beep(beepgen3, beepgenn3);
            Console.Beep(beepgen4, beepgenn4);
            Console.Beep(beepgen5, beepgenn5);
            Console.Beep(beepgen6, beepgenn6);
            Console.Beep(beepgen7, beepgenn7);
            Console.Beep(beepgen8, beepgenn8);
```