# c# beep through system speaker - direct access to sys. speaker

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, beep

I've used the following code and it expects to sound through the system speaker. The code really sounds but through the sound card (desktop speaker/headphone).

I think it will be possible to make some sound directly using system beep speaker since in device manager it displays the driver for that. Is there any work around for this.

** Not through default speaker / headphone.  -- os win7 or 8 **

```
  Console.Beep(i, 100);
```

---

**EDIT**

It is confirmed that win7(at least 64bit or both and newer ver.) dose not use system speaker and instead they routes the call to default sound device.
But my concern is,If the system speaker(hardware) is available and connected, isn't there any other way to access the device directly without using built in APIs to windows. I'd like to do some experiments on this(direct hardware access) and if you can at least provide me some starting point for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the computer beep in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321135/how-can-i-make-the-computer-beep-in-c)

Comment: One of the comments links to this explanation [What’s up with the Beep driver in Windows 7?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2010/01/04/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Fine. Isnt there any other way to access the beep hardware directly.

Comment: @ Glen Thomas : Not a duplicate. This question is asked regarding to win 7 and the previous one is posted 8 years ago it address only for pre win7 OSs.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022207/Make-Buzzer-Internal-Speaker-Sound-in-Windows-bit worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

According to article below, it is not supported in Windows 7 x64.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2010/01/04/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 hardware requirements for 64 bit machines didn’t include support for an 8254 PIC chip, which is required for the internal PC speaker beep, so Microsoft changed how this functionality works for Windows 7 and the beep instruction is now re-routed to your Windows audio output instead.

So, it can't be done.

Comment: But the driver is there. Cant we use it in any manner and there should be a reason to have it in the device manager.

Comment: Larry says "For Windows 7, we resolved the issue completely – we moved all the functionality that used to be contained in Beep.Sys into the user mode system sounds agent – now when you call the Beep() API instead of manipulating the 8254 chip the call is re-routed into a user mode agent which actually plays the sounds."

Comment: OK. So then then cant we directly deal with the beep device bypassing the API.

Comment: Not all computers have an internal speaker and 8254 chip since Windows 7 made the hardware completely redundant. The Windows API does not support what you are asking for, so I guess your only option to communicate with internal speaker for computers that have one would to be to write your own device driver and install it on any machine that you need to use it on. How possible that is I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a configuration of your device is needded. You can try to understand from this: https://superuser.com/a/230167