# Console.WriteLine() Making a a sound when Convert.ToChar(7) is put in it

Tags: c#, .net, console

When I run the code

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte(7)))
```

My computer makes a noise, I have confirmed this to work on a Windows 7 computer as well, I am using windows 10. My assumption is that it either has to do with how Unicode or the console handles this character but I'm not really certain. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For reference, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321135/how-can-i-make-the-computer-beep-in-c) and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38176987/21567). Make sure speaker is on.

Comment: type Alt + 7 in standard console and you will hear same noise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char` 7 is the BELL character. In early days, you could make the motherboard make a chime with just a key on your keyboard or a character put on the terminal.

When you output that character using a command line program, it plays that sound.